# linear 4×4 system of nonhomogeneous differential equations with repeated eigenvalues.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution of this system of linear Nonhomogeneous differential equation:
$$X'=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &1  &1 &-1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 1 &0\\ 
0 &0  &-1 &0\\
0 &-1  &0 &0
\end{bmatrix}X + 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^t \\ 
2t \\ 
e^{-2t} \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as an aproach, I found the eigenvalue $-1$ with multiplicity of 4.
And I found two eigenvectors:
$$V^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$V^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
so i got two answers for the Corresponding homogeneous equation:
$$X^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$
and $$X^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$

since we have 2 eigenvectors and one eigenvalue with multiplicity of 4, I tried to find the other two answers by assuming them as $X=vte^{-t} + ηe^{-t}$ and I got:

$X^{(3)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}te^{-t} + \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$

$X^{(4)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}te^{-t} + \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 
-1 \\ 
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$

I wanna know if the Answers I found are correct.
if Yes, we have:
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-t} &0  &0 &-e^{-t}\\ 
0 & e^{-t} & te^{-t} &te^{-t}-e^{-t}\\ 
e^{-t} &0  &e^{-t} &0\\
0 &e^{-t}  &te^{-t}+e^{-t} &te^{-t}
\end{bmatrix}$$
using the Variation of Parameters method, we have to inverse X to find the answer but A is singular $(detA=0)$ :(

where am I going wrong? can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You assumed that the Jordan blocks for $-1$ were of sizes $\{2,2\}$ – they're in fact of sizes $\{3,1\}$:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1&1\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\0&-1&1&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1&1\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$
So one homogeneous solution is a vector times $t^2e^{-t}$:
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}1-t&t&t&-t\\-t+t^2/2&1-t^2/2&t-t^2/2&t^2/2\\0&0&1&0\\t^2/2&-t-t^2/2&-t^2/2&1+t+t^2/2\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$

Comment: I don't understand something. in Jordan blocks all the arrays above Main diagonal must be 1, but here the array 3×4 isn't 1, why? and in the matrix of eigenvectors where does the third column come from?